# Dynamically adding node value in MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: c#, mvcsitemapprovider

I need to  create the breadcrumb dynamically using MvcSiteMapProvider like below

```
Ticket > Details > {id}
Ticket >Details > {id} > Edit
```

Value of `{id}` is dynamic value. i am not using MvcSiteMap xml files.Instead i am using .NET Attributes like below

```
// GET: /Checkout/Index 
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Checkout", ParentKey = "Store", Key = id)] 
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

How can i achieve my requirement?

Comment: -https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node

I think it's useful link for your requirement.

Comment: There is a working demo of this exact scenario here: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position. Note that it does not matter how you configure your nodes, they all work the same way once they are loaded.